# How do I crop to an arbitrary aspect ratio in VLC media player?

Tags: vlc-media-player, crop, aspect-ratio

The VLC crop settings only contain some aspect ratios. How can I crop to something not listed? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Tools, preferences, bottom left "show settings: all", video, custom crop ratios list.

The ratios must not contain decimals. For example,

1.66666:1 * 3 = 5:3

[image]